# In Microsoft SQL Server, what's the difference between not checking "Grant" and checking "Deny"?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

For each database, I can set user securables by checking and unchecking Grant, With Grant, and Deny. Grant and Deny can't be checked at the same time, which makes sense. But they can both be unchecked. What does this mean? Why isn't it like a radio button between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't `grant` a permission, the user inherits permissions from other groups that they are a member of.

When you `deny` a permission, you prevent that inheritance from applying to that permission.

Comment: Moments after asking, I started to suspect something like this but couldn't phrase it coherently. Thank you!